# Help with Formula in validation rules

Tags: administration, formula

I have couple of custom fields

Tuser_*c Checkbox
Tdate*_c Date

I want to have the tdate field to be required if the Tuser is true

```
AND( $User.Tuser__c ,ISNULL( $User.Tdate__c ))
```

This doesnt fire the validation rule when i leave Tuser_*c as true and leave the TDate*_c blank(Nothing entered in the field)

Is there something i am missing

Comment: As mast0r mentioned in his answer, the validation rule works without the $user reference. Any reason why it wouldnt work with the $user reference?

Comment: All `$variables` are related to "who's looking at the data" (current user, his profile, his role, his session id... Hierarchical custom settings fall here as well) or simply some cached data (custom labels). All the rest is hard "what the data is". So - what were you trying to do? Allow only certain users to perform edits? Or check if the lookup to user stored on the record meets some condition? Looks like it's a data rule and not "who's editing" rule - so without `$user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to use `ISBLANK` and remove `$User` reference:

```
AND(Tuser__c, ISBLANK(Tdate__c))
```

Comment: That didnt work too :(

Comment: @Prady Is it for the `User` object?

Comment: Yup, its user object

Comment: @Prady I've tried this without `$User` reference. In my Org it works fine. Updated my example.

Comment: ok let me try removing the $user

Comment: @Prady I hope your validation rule is active :)

Comment: Its active and working when i remove the $User

Comment: Any idea why it wouldnt take using $User reference. I am happy it worked :) Thanks

Comment: @Prady I think it is because $User is a global reference to the object.